# How to efficiently query items with tags

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

My schema looks something like this:

```
items ( id, title)
tags (id, name )
items_tags ( item_id, tag_id )
```

I want to **efficiently** get a list of items, each with its own set of tags. Presumably with **one query** to the database. By **efficient** I mean that the query should return its result in the fastest time possible, using the least amount of server and database resources, like CPU & RAM. Presumably, the number of items and tags is over several millions and the number of parallel queries is high. Highload and all the things. So something like:

```
// Get all items with tags
'Item-1' has 'Tag-1', 'Tag-2'
'Item-2' has 'Tag-3', 'Tag-5'
...
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 10. So there are actually two questions:

1. How the **efficient** SQL query to retrieve such data from such a schema would look like?
2. Maybe the schema of the data can be redesigned to be more efficient for such a case? Maybe I should use Arrays, HStore, JSONB?

Comment: I think what he means is efficient, or rather most efficient. And this is SO after all, not all answers you get are effective ;)

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is good for a many-to-many relationship.

All you need to add are primary and foreign key constraints.

To query the data you need, simply join the three tables on their natural join conditions.

To get an aggregated list, use an aggregate function like `string_agg` and group by `items.title`.